# Spring mvc start up optimization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have a spring mvc based web project, i have many urls and i defined a filter for each url for getting my custom roles for urls,
my issue is that when i start up the project on tomcat, spring mvc mapped all my urls (that i set using requestMapping annotation) and it takes time,
is there any approach to decrease this time?
for example lazy loading for any urls, map it when it triggered and ...

in my servlet.xml

```
<beans:bean id="warehouseCreateFilter" class="shiro.RolesAuthorizationFilter">
     <beans:property name="roles" value="${warehouseCreate}"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "many urls" ?

Do you know what's taking the time on startup ?

I usually profile an application to look at specific bottlenecks.

Comment: when i start up project on tomcat, spring mvc mapped any requestMapping (urls that i have prepared throw @RequestMapping), the log is "RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register:543  - Mapped "{[/warehouseCreate],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String", the bottleneck is here, taking times for mapping all URLs

Comment: the used annotation: @RequestMapping(value = "/warehouseCreate", method = RequestMethod.GET)